# How to sum up data in specific periods of date time in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data frame with more then 1mil values. The task is, to sum it up these values in the range of every 5 minutes.
In other words from 0 to first 5 minutes, then 10 minutes, then 15 and so on. But there are over 30-33 days.
This is my data:

```
                                    Size
                        DateTime                              
2018-10-19 04:14:01.015000+00:00     2
2018-10-19 04:14:01.546000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:01.290000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:01.291000+00:00    10
2018-10-19 04:15:01.821000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:01.821000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:02.352000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:02.352000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:02.883000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:02.884000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:03.413000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:03.414000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:03.943000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:03.943000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:04.474000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:04.474000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:05.003000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:05.003000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:05.334000+00:00     1
2018-10-19 04:15:05.336000+00:00     1
...
2018-11-26 19:59:33.928000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:37.221000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:41.808000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:42.338000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:45.520000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:52.059000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:52.589000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:54.714000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:55.244000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:56.297000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:57.888000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 19:59:59.008000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 20:00:00.071000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 20:51:04.606000+00:00     1
2018-11-26 20:51:57.307000+00:00     1
```

As you can see, it's pretty lots of rows in there. I have some ideas about how to do it, but I'm stuck.
Well, data range could be set like:

```
data[data.index.minute % 5 == 0]
```

But how could I sum values before this and in the next range ?

Comment: Can you please clarify how you expect the output to look like?

Comment: @perl I need to analyze those data and then plot it to see what time is the best size

Comment: So do you want to sum up all the values with minute % 5 == 0, 1,..., 4 (so 5 groups in total) or resample the data by 5 min intervals and sum up values in each interval? (or is it something other than these two options?)

Comment: @perl nope, note 5 groups, but you're absolutely right about intervals (for example: from started point to next 5 minutes - sum up, then, from 5 minutes to 10 minutes - sum up in and so on). Sorry for my English, I hope you got it correct

Comment: OK, cool, so then I think `resample` should work, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `resample`:

```
data.resample('5min')['Size'].sum()
```

Comment: sorry for interrupt, but could you help me to deal with one more problem: I need to move all days in one to see how size depends on time

Comment: You mean time of the day, right? Let's say you already have you resampled dataset `x = data.resample('5min').sum()`, then you can group it by time regardless of the date with `x.groupby(x.index.time).sum()`

Comment: damn, you're the maestro, I wish I could be such a badass data analyst))))

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) here with `freq=5min`

**note** I only used the top rows of your example data, above the `..`

```
df_sum = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='5min', axis=1)).Size.sum().reset_index()

print(df_sum)

             DateTime  Size
0 2018-10-19 04:10:00     3
1 2018-10-19 04:15:00    27
```

Comment: thanks, it looks properly, but I got this error : IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Comment: If you reset your index with `.reset_index()`, your `DateTime` index becomes a column and then it should work,

Comment: I think the problem is in DateTime, it's not a column, but index. Actually, whis works - data.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'DateTime', freq ='300s', axis=1)).Size.sum()

Comment: you're really helped me out, much obliged!